# "Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0)"

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio-3.1, android-googleapiclient

My project was working all right but today, when I tried to rebuild it, started showing above error. I checked the previous answers to the similar questions but couldn't resolve the issue. This is the build.gradle(Module: app) file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "soumyadeb.com.mywatercan"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1"

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**Following is my build.gradle(Project: ..)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**I am getting this error.**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add google() in your build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.1'` for all play-services
And I don't think we need `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'` in Project build.gradle